# why does my code not continue to read the entire file

Tags: java, compiler-errors, output, filereader

My code when I compile it and run outputs the first line of the file then it says all of this:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
at Popcorn1.main(Popcorn1.java:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

And the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Popcorn1 {

public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
    printHeader();
    File file;

    do {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the the file name");
        String filename = in.next();

        file = new File(filename);
    } while (!file.exists());

    FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(file);
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(inputFile);

    System.out.println("        PopCorn Co-op");
    System.out.println("                                      Production in Hundreds");
    System.out.println("                                      of Pint Jars Per Acre");
    System.out.println("                                  1   2   3   4   5   6");
    System.out.println("Farm Name                      ---|---|---|---|---|---|");
    System.out.println();

    // Printing out title and table header for reader to easily read data
    String errorMSG = " ";
    while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
        String inputLine = inFile.nextLine();
        //System.out.print(inputLine);
        int position;
        String name;
        int jars;
        double acres;
        position = inputLine.indexOf(',');//Get the Location of the comma to use as a delimiter

        name = inputLine.substring(0, position); //Everything to the left of the comma is the farm name
        System.out.printf("%-31s", name);

        inputLine = inputLine.substring(position + 2, inputLine.length());           //rest of the string 
        Scanner line = new Scanner(inputLine);
        {
            //acres = 0;

            jars = 0;
            acres = 0;
            if (line.hasNextDouble()) {
                acres = line.nextDouble();
            } else {
                errorMSG += "There is missing data";
            }
            // jars = 0;
            if (line.hasNextInt()) {

                jars = line.nextInt();
            } else {
                errorMSG += "There is missing data";
            }
        }

        int starsConversion = (int) (jars / acres / 25);

        for (int i = 1; i < starsConversion; i++) {
            if (i == 20) {
                System.out.print("#");
            } else {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
        }
        if (starsConversion < 20) {
            for (int i = 1; i < (21 - starsConversion); i++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.print("|");
            {
                System.out.println(); //go to the next line
            }
        }

        System.out.println(errorMSG);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to be sure what is going on without the file, but it looks like

```
position = inputLine.indexOf(',');
```

is returning -1 (it doesn't find ',' in the file), thus giving you an invalid index.

Try printing out the position after you calculate to make sure that it is valid.

```
System.out.println("Position: " + position);
System.out.println("Length: " + inputLine.length());
System.out.println("Trimmed: " + inputLine.trim().length());
```

If the length is 0, or just whitespace there is not going to be a comma in it.

This might be fixed with adding following after reading the nextLine:

```
if(inputLine.trim().length() == 0) 
    continue
if(inputLine.indexOf(",") == -1) 
    System.out.println("There is no comma on this line: " + inputLine);
```

Comment: can you type an expample for that. What do you mean print it after I cal it. I am already printing it out